# Integers family with factorization exponent equal to 1

Tags: abstract-algebra, number-theory

Do (positive) integers whose prime factorization's exponent vector $(e_1, ..., e_n)$ satisfies: $$\gcd(e_1, ..., e_n)=1$$ have a name and/or an algebraic (or any) characterization other than "that extension of the square-free integers"?

Answer (score 2):

The condition $\gcd(e_1,\dots ,e_n)=1$ is satisfied if and only if the given number is not a non-trivial perfect power (that means not a number of the form $a^b$, where $a,b>1$ are integers).

So, we could name such numbers as non-powers.

Comment: Thanks for the love Peter but... :-) other than that you think anyone put at least a small theory around them?

Comment: Sorry, but I do not understand this comment.

Comment: I meant: I appreciate your attention, I upvoted your answer, but your answer is trivial. Possibly my fault by not adding a context but anyways: do you know of any relevant algebraic (or any) characterization of this set? Square free integers have multiple characterizations, conjectures, wide bibliography and even their own Wikipedia article. If something exists for our set I haven't found it yet, thus I'm asking.

Comment: If the answer is trivial, Lorenzo, how come you didn't come up with it yourself? For what it's worth, the numbers are tabulated at http://oeis.org/A007916 and you will see there aren't many links there to "characterizations, conjectures, bibliography, Wikipedia".

Comment: I think the reason there little evidence of work on these numbers is that the complementary set, the perfect powers, http://oeis.org/A001597 has gotten all the attention. In much the same way as there's a lot more research on the primes than there is on the composites.

Comment: @GerryMyerson ofc I tried various combinations similiar to Peter's suggestion already. Naming is pointless unless a name means something (serves a purpose: a topic of research in our case). As I already told to Peter, it's likely my fault for not adding enough context. Thanks to your comment now we know that the best answer would have been OEIS' naming: "not a perfect power". And shame on me for not trying OEIS already (or maybe I tried it but wasn't happy with the result and forgot about it)

Comment: I guess it may be considered rude or pointless to answer yours own question in a situation like this. If anyone wants to proceed within a couple of days gathering some info from OEIS I'll be happy to upvote and close the topic (because apparently the topic has not received much scientific attention). Otherwise I'll do it myself.

Comment: Answering your own question, based on what you've learned since posing it, is neither rude nor pointless but actually encouraged on stackexchange sites.